# How to compile "_ctypes" module for ARM using VS2012

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm compiling Python 2.6.8 version for ARM systems using VS2012, and I have some compilation problems on the "_ctypes" module.
  Does anyone can help me to understand this problem ?
  Here are the compilation problems:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: _ctypes, Configuration: Release ARM ------
1>  _ctypes.c
1>  callbacks.c
1>..\Modules\_ctypes\callbacks.c(441): error C2065: 'FFI_STDCALL' : undeclared identifier
1>  callproc.c
1>  cfield.c
1>  ffi.c
1>..\Modules\_ctypes\libffi_msvc\ffi.c(113): warning C4018: '>' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>..\Modules\_ctypes\libffi_msvc\ffi.c(218): error C2065: 'FFI_STDCALL' : undeclared identifier
1>..\Modules\_ctypes\libffi_msvc\ffi.c(218): error C2051: case expression not constant
1>..\Modules\_ctypes\libffi_msvc\ffi.c(285): error C4235: nonstandard extension             used : '_asm'     keyword not supported on this architecture
1>..\Modules\_ctypes\libffi_msvc\ffi.c(285): error C2065: 'mov' : undeclared identifier
1>..\Modules\_ctypes\libffi_msvc\ffi.c(285): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before     identifier 'eax'
1>..\Modules\_ctypes\libffi_msvc\ffi.c(285): error C2065: 'eax' : undeclared identifier
..... etc
```

Comment: is it possible to see ffi.c ?

Comment: At the top of `libffi_msvc\ffi.c` it says "**x86** Foreign Function Interface", so I doubt it should work for ARM.

Comment: thks for your answer.

Comment: Thks for the answer. I've compiled it but not with this lib.